# Using property in canvas results in TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to implement my own ProgressBar* widget.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
<MyProgressBar@Widget>:
    max: 1
    value: 0
    limited_value: min(self.value, self.max)
    # Filled ratio should never be 0 or 1
    # otherwise it would cause size_hints equal to 0,
    # that is, None-type value, resulting in ignoring size_hint
    filled_ratio: max(.00001, min(.9999, float(self.value) / self.max))
    empty_ratio: 1-self.filled_ratio
    filled_color: 0,1,0,1
    empty_color: .6,.6,.6,.4

    size_hint_y: .5
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: root.filled_color
        Rectangle:
            size: root.width * root.filled_ratio, root.height
            pos: root.pos
        Color:
            rgba: root.empty_color
        Rectangle:
            size: root.width * root.empty_ratio, root.height
            pos: root.x + root.width*root.filled_ratio, root.y

<MainWidget>:
    MyProgressBar

"""
Builder.load_string(kv)

class MainWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MySimpleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        main = MainWidget(orientation='vertical')
        return main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MySimpleApp().run()
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
 BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 20:
 ...
      18:            rgba: root.filled_color
      19:        Rectangle:
 >>   20:            size: root.width * root.filled_ratio, root.height
      21:            pos: root.pos
      22:        Color:
 ...
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Replacing `root.filled_ratio` and `root.empty_ratio` in `canvas` with any float makes the error disappear. So, `canvas` sees `root.filled_ratio` as `None` for some reason, while it should be a float.

The error also disappears if instead of:

```
filled_ratio: max(.00001, min(.9999, float(self.value) / self.max))
empty_ratio: 1-self.filled_ratio
```

.. I use:

```
filled_ratio: .4
empty_ratio: .6
```

What am I doing wrong?

<sub>*there is already a [ProgressBar](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.progressbar.html?highlight=progressbar#) in Kivy.</sub>

Comment: Did you try breaking the expression that calculates filled_ratio out by itself and seeing if it evaluates correctly?

Comment: @PaulRooney Yes. If I only change `filled_ratio: ` to `.4` i still get the same error on the next property that uses it, that is `empty_ratio`, when called in canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Simply defining the properties in python before using them in kv-language fixes the issue:

```
class MyProgressBar(Widget):
    filled_ratio = NumericProperty(0)
    empty_ratio = NumericProperty(0)
```

<sub>(Note: I don't consider this a complete answer since it doesn't explain *why* this happens. Feel free to create an answer that addresses fully the issue)</sub>

Comment: When a "new" property is introduced in kv the property will be an ObjectProperty (which defaults to `None`) (see [under the third example](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file)). I'm not sure why it takes the default instead of the actual value. When defined as a NumericProperty the default is 0 which doesn't throw an error.